# Parse Amazon S3 Events for general understanding

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to learn more about AWS "Events" when interacting with AWS Lambda.  In the code below, a .csv file is uploaded to AWS S3.   S3 generates an event and the lambda function below parses the .csv and uploads to DynamoDB.  The code extrapolates the the source bucket and file key.  I'm wondering how I obtain access to information other than bucket and name.

I'm assuming the event parsing starts at line 14 `for record in event['Records']:`

```
import csv
import os
import tempfile

import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    **for record in event['Records']:**
        source_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            download_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, key)
            s3.download_file(source_bucket, key, download_path)
            items = read_csv(download_file)

            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for item in items:
                    batch.put_item(Item=item)


def read_csv(file):
    items=[]
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = {}
            data['Meta'] = {}
            data['Year'] = int(row['Year'])
            data['Title'] = row['Title'] or None
            data['Meta']['Length'] = int(row['Length'] or 0)
            data['Meta']['Length'] = int(row['Length'] or 0)
            data['Meta']['Subject'] = row['Subject'] or None
            data['Meta']['Actor'] = row['Actor'] or None
            data['Meta']['Actress'] = row['Actress'] or None
            data['Meta']['Director'] = row['Director'] or None
            data['Meta']['Popularity'] = row['Popularity'] or None
            data['Meta']['Awards'] = row['Awards'] == 'Yes'
            data['Meta']['Image'] = row['Image'] or None
            data['Meta'] = {k: v for k,
                            v in data['Meta'].items() if v is not None}
            items.append(data)
    return items
```

Thank you

Comment: what other information are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about what other information you can extract out of the event message, the event message structure is defined in the S3 documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

The structure is copied below for convenience.

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.2",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
         "eventTime":The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, when Amazon S3 finished processing the request,
         "eventName":"event-type",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-user-who-caused-the-event"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"ip-address-where-request-came-from"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"Amazon S3 generated request ID",
            "x-amz-id-2":"Amazon S3 host that processed the request"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-bucket-owner"
               },
               "arn":"bucket-ARN"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
               "size":object-size,
               "eTag":"object eTag",
               "versionId":"object version if bucket is versioning-enabled, otherwise null",
               "sequencer": "a string representation of a hexadecimal value used to determine event sequence, 
                   only used with PUTs and DELETEs"
            }
         },
         "glacierEventData": {
            "restoreEventData": {
               "lifecycleRestorationExpiryTime": "The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, of Restore Expiry",
               "lifecycleRestoreStorageClass": "Source storage class for restore"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```